# cutting a string at spaces python

Tags: string, python-2.7, spaces

I am beginning to learn python and want to cut a string at the spaces; so 'hello world' becomes 'hello' and 'world'. To do this i want to save the locations of the spaces in a list, but i can't figure out how to do this. In order to find the spaces i do this:

```
    def string_splitting(text):
        i = 0
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if (text[i]==' '):
```

After saving them in the list i want to display them with text[:list[1]] (or something like that)

Can anyone help me with the saving it in a list part; and is this even possible?

(Another way to cut the string is welcome to :-) )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split:

```
"hello world my name is".split(' ')
```

It will give you a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i tried to do it without the split option, should have said that in the question..

anyways this worked;

```
    def split_stringj(text):
        a = text.count(' ')
        p = len(text)
        l = [-1]
        x = 0
        y = 1
        for x in range(p):
            if (text[x]==' '):
                l.append(x)
                y += 1
        l.append(p)
        print l
        for x in range(len(l)-1):
            print text[l[x]+1:l[x+1]]
```